# Can I validate and prevent numbers exceeding a certain value for different inputs with one function?

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm using this script:

```
let validate = function(e) {
  let t = e.value;
  e.value = (t.indexOf(".") >= 0) ? (t.substr(0, t.indexOf(".")) + t.substr(t.indexOf("."), 4)) : t;
}
```

And, being honest here, I get that the first part says we need a number or 0, not 100% sure what the second part is, but the third part limits to 3 decimal places. But I would also like to add a clause that no number above 150 can be added either (but could have 149.999). Is this possible using this?

If I wanted to have different validations for 7 different inputs (eg, some can have numbers up to 10 where others can have numbers only less than 1 and others up to 150). Do I have to build a separate validate for each of these inputs, or can I somehow attach them here via their #ID?

Comment: `e.value = Math.min(e.value, 150)`;

Answer (score 2):

`e` seems to be input. So you have different possiblities

1. have a fixed ruleset for each of your inputs in the validation function

   ```
    function validate(e) {
      switch (e.id) {
        case "input_1":
          //do validiations for input 1
          break;
        case "input_2":
          //do validation for input 2
          break;
        default:
          //no rules for all others 
          break;
      }
    }
   ```
2. make a more generic approach with a set of possible constraints

   ```
   <input type="number" data-maxvalue="150"/>
   <input type="number" data-maxdigits="3"/>
   <input type="number" data-minvalue="5" data-maxvalue="10"/>

   function validate(e) {
      if (e.dataset.minvalue && +(e.value) < +(e.dataset.minvalue)) {
        e.value = +(e.dataset.minvalue)
      }
      if (e.dataset.maxvalue && +(e.value) > +(e.dataset.maxvalue)) {
        e.value = +(e.dataset.maxvalue)
      }
      if (e.dataset.maxdigits) {
        var t = e.value;
        e.value = (t.indexOf(".") >= 0) ? (t.substr(0, t.indexOf(".")) + t.substr(t.indexOf("."), +(e.dataset.maxdigits)+1)) : t;          
      }
      ...
   }
   ```
3. Use built-in formvalidation, which might possibly cover your use cases https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

   ```
    <input type="number" required max="150" min="10" step="0.001">
   ```

Comment: I second this answer specifically 3rd possibility as this uses the inbuilt validation.

Comment: Definitely the second answer! I'm going to try that later today. The third isn't effective because I have type="text" because number gave errors somewhere (I can't recall where, but it did). Thanks, I'll let you know how it goes when I try and then select this as the answer should it work :)

Comment: @PaulDavis If you are expecting numbers in your input, you should definitively try to use `type="number"`. If you need to use `type="text"` eventhough it's actually a number you should investigate that issue. You might have a problem in your data ...

Comment: I can't recall what the issue was now, I will try returning it back to number, I may have fixed the issue somewhere along the line. I'll give it a try

Comment: I am trying in JSBin - this all works except the maxdigits https://jsbin.com/wulocav/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @PaulDavis You should probably remove the invalid parts from the script (ie the inputs and the `...` in the script )

Comment: @PaulDavis When I remove the invalid parts of the js your bin works fine for me. Maybe you get your value with `,` instead of `.` as a decimal separator? Except of course one thing: you are running the validation `oninput` (ie each keystroke) which prohibits entering for instance `20` into the first box, because when the first digit `2` is entered, it's immediately replaced with `10`. Maybe you should do the validation for instance `onblur` (when the input loses focus)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely add another line of code to the validate function to test if the value is greater than 150 a clamp it:

```
if (e.value > 150)
    e.value = 150;
```

I don't know how you call the validate function, but the maximum value can possibly be set using a second argument of the function (`let validate = function(e, max)`).

Comment: Using oninput="validate(this)"